# How to kick off Facebook Messenger conversation with user

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I've seen this use case a few times.

- A user goes to a company's web site and places an order with the company.
- User logs into Facebook.
- Messenger window shows up that says order confirmation # and now there's a chat between you and the business.

I'm trying to figure out how this is done.

Of course, if the user has given the app permissions or there was some Facebook integration on check out, then presumably the company has captured the user id and can send messages.

Is there any possible way that a company can send a message to a user by simply knowing their e-mail address? I think FB ids are scoped to Apps so even if you knew the user's FB Id, the ID on your app would be different. Any ideas?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking

Answer (score 0):

I did it with ruby on rails.Let me give my articles about messenger bot.

[This](https://chatbotslife.com/create-a-facebook-messenger-bot-with-ruby-on-rails-4ffd8b851135#.1jtlbr6qp) link show from scratch. and it uses [this](https://github.com/hyperoslo/facebook-messenger) gem to make it happen. These are so useful articles. if you have additional questions, please let me know.